# gdal.Open IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, gdal

I am new here and hope I will find some help.

I working with following Code to Calculate NDVI from Sentinel 2-A

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal 

in_dir = 'C:\\temp\\'

# Search directory for desired bands
red_file = glob.glob(in_dir + '**B04.jp2') # red band
nir_file = glob.glob(in_dir + '**B08.jp2') # nir band

# Define a function to calculate NDVI using band arrays for red, NIR bands
def ndvi(red, nir):
    return ((nir - red)/(nir + red))
    #return (NIR.astype(float) - RED.astype(float)) / (NIR+RED)


# Open each band using gdal
red_link = gdal.Open(red_file[0])
nir_link = gdal.Open(nir_file[0])

# read in each band as array and convert to float for calculations
red = red_link.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)
nir = nir_link.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)

# Call the ndvi() function on red, NIR bands
ndvi2 = ndvi(red, nir)

# Create output filename based on input name
outfile_name = red_file[0].split('_B')[0] + '_NDVI.tif'

x_pixels = ndvi2.shape[0] # number of pixels in x
y_pixels = ndvi2.shape[1] # number of pixels in y

# Set up output GeoTIFF
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

# Create driver using output filename, x and y pixels, # of bands, and datatype
ndvi_data = driver.Create(outfile_name,x_pixels, y_pixels, 1,gdal.GDT_Float32)

# Set NDVI array as the 1 output raster band
ndvi_data.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(ndvi2)

# Setting up the coordinate reference system of the output GeoTIFF
geotrans=red_link.GetGeoTransform() # Grab input GeoTranform information
proj=red_link.GetProjection() # Grab projection information from input file

# now set GeoTransform parameters and projection on the output file
ndvi_data.SetGeoTransform(geotrans)
ndvi_data.SetProjection(proj)
ndvi_data.FlushCache()
ndvi_data=None
###############################################################################
```

I get the following IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\NDVI3.py", line 31, in <module>
    red_link = gdal.Open(red_file[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Could it be that my GDAL version doesn't recognize jp2 format?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like there's no element in your list `red_file` ... did you check if  `glob` actually returns filenames?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand in "IndexError : list index out of range" ? Your list is obviously empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your are right, the output of `glob` was empty! There is e issue with the directory if I define it like:

```
# Search directory for desired bands
red_file = glob.glob(in_dir + '**B04.jp2') # red band
nir_file = glob.glob(in_dir + '**B08.jp2') # nir band
```

to test it I solved it with:

```
red_file = glob.glob('C:\\temp\\T32TMT_20180326T103021_B04_10m.jp2') # red band
nir_file = glob.glob('C:\\temp\\T32TMT_20180326T103021_B08_10m.jp2') # nir band
```

But now I get the issue that `gdal.Open` does not working as supposed. After `gdal.Open` there is again a empty list what appears in the following Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\NDVI3.py", line 52, in <module>
    red = red_link.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

Now I ask myself again, could it be that my GDAL version (2.2.3) doesn't recognize jp2 format?